# Are we supposed to keep rep from deleted questions?

Tags: discussion

I posted a question today that I knew was a duplicate because I couldn't find the other.  It quickly got two up votes.

But then someone pointed me to the other, so I deleted today's.  The rep did not change.

Comment: FYI you usually don't need to delete duplicates (so long as you did make a reasonable effort to search before posting). A correctly closed duplicate posted in good faith can be a helpful signpost for people who use search terms you used in your version of the question that weren't in the original

Answer (score 2):

No, in the situation you described the reputation earned from that question is not kept. And you did not earn any reputation today, as the [reputation history shows](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau?tab=reputation).

I suppose you did not see a reputation drop because it takes a little while for reputation to be recalculated and then for the next value to be reflected on the site (given the amount of caching that is going on).

For completeness, [this is the only situation when you can keep reputation from a deleted post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/):

> if you’ve contributed something worthwhile to the site, you should keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets deleted. “Worthwhile” here is defined as,
>
> - A score of 3 or greater
> - Visible on the site for at least 60 days

Comment: Yes, I see that it has now been reversed.  Oddly, it says it happened yesterday, and shows the removal twice.